# HOW TO USE CASE STATEMENT IN MONGODB WHERE CONDITION

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to Mongo Db and would appreciate some help with this query.

```
 DATA:

       {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ba2442e9b75ee04d429ed34"),
            "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-101",
            "CITY_ID" : "200-1239",
            "EVENT" : "0"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ba2442e9b75ee04d429ed34"),
            "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-101",
            "CITY_ID" : "200-1239",
            "EVENT" : "2"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ba2442e9b75ee04d429ed34"),
            "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-101",
            "CITY_ID" : "200-1239",
            "EVENT" : "3"
        },{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ba2442e9b75ee04d429ed34"),
            "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-101",
            "CITY_ID" : "800-1239",
            "EVENT" : "1"
        }
```

I wrote the following aggregation pipeline WITH USING MATCH CONDITION 
"CITY_ID" : "200-1239" AND "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-101" AND BUT HOW TO CHANGE EVENT  WHEN '1'THEN 'I' (OR)  EVENT WHEN '2' THEN 'U' (OR) EVENT WHEN '3' THEN 'D' (OR) EVENT WHEN '0' THEN 'V' ANY ONE PLEASE SUGGEST ME.

```
db.COLLECTION.aggregate([{

{
        $match:{
            $and:[{"CITY_ID" : "200-1239","RESOURCE_ID" : "100-101"}]
        }
    },

 ])
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ba2442e9b75ee04d429ed34"),
            "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-101",
            "CITY_ID" : "200-1239",
            "EVENT" : "V"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ba2442e9b75ee04d429ed34"),
            "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-101",
            "CITY_ID" : "200-1239",
            "EVENT" : "U"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ba2442e9b75ee04d429ed34"),
            "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-101",
            "CITY_ID" : "200-1239",
            "EVENT" : "D"
        },{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ba2442e9b75ee04d429ed34"),
            "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-101",
            "CITY_ID" : "200-1239",
            "EVENT" : "I"
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$switch` in `$project`

```
db.COLLECTION.aggregate([

      {
  $match: {
    $and: [{ "CITY_ID": "200-1239", "RESOURCE_ID": "100-101" }]
  }
},

{
  "$project": {
    "RESOURCE_ID": 1,
    "CITY_ID" : 1,
    "EVENT": {
      $switch: {
        branches: [
          { case: { "$eq": ["$EVENT", "1"] }, then: "I" },
          { case: { "$eq": ["$EVENT", "2"] }, then: "U" },
          { case: { "$eq": ["$EVENT", "3"] }, then: "D" },
          { case: { "$eq": ["$EVENT", "0"] }, then: "V" }
        ],
        default: "Z" //You can set default
      }
    }

    }
  } ])
```

reference Link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/

Comment: Hi IftekharDani iam trying this code some trow error  Unexpected token ] @ IftekharDani

Comment: @Naresh Please Check, I have Updated my answer. The issue is just missing brackets.

Comment: Thank you @  IftekharDani  but how to remove default values

Comment: You can also use `default:"$EVENT"`

Comment: ok thank you @  IftekharDani